# Adding different CSS for space and text to an text type input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `text` type input in an html form as bellow:

`<input type="text" id="tag" name="tag">`

Now, I want to add style on that input text based on user's input. This style need to be different for `text` and `space`.

For example: if someone enters `php java python` in the input field then I want to style `php`, `java` and `python` with specific background where their `internal spaces` will have different background.

Is it possible? If possible then how?

Comment: With 1K rep you really aught to know to write a [mcve]

Comment: You can't style text in an input, you'd need to use contentEditable e.g. `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`. Then you can parse the user's input, split it up by spaces, and wrap the words in `<span>`s and give them styles.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a single HTML element... I think one can use multiple `span`/`label` elements created dynamically using JavaScript with different styling based on tokens!

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think that rep come from all the rules(or smartness) you know about stackoverflow. Besides, the question I am asking here has nothing special to say about what you have mentioned. By the way, thanks for advising, it was really an unknown term from me. I think that's how we learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *yes and no*.
Yes it is possible, but it is not possible with input only.

You cannot put elements inside input tags, but You could have some kind of container which would handle this part for You.

I've attached very simple and naive example, it could be done way better, but it shows You the concept.

Text inside input is being split by space, and new element for each word and space is created.

You could do something like that, but with styled input inside container. Then You should listen for input change. When user press space, You should get the word which user wrote, create new element for word (and also one more for space), append it to container, and clear the input, so it would be ready for next, new word.

```js
const textContainer = document.querySelector('#textContainer')

document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => textToElements(target.value))

const textToElements = (text) => {
  const words = text.split(' ')
  const wordsElements = words.map(createWordElement)
 
  clearWordsContainer()
  wordsElements.forEach(putWordElement)
}

const createWordElement = (word) => {
  const element = document.createElement('span')

  element.classList.add('word')
  element.textContent = word

  return element
}

const putWordElement = (element) => {
  const spaceElement = document.createElement('span')

  spaceElement.classList.add('space')
  spaceElement.textContent = ' '

  textContainer.appendChild(element)
  textContainer.appendChild(spaceElement)
}

const clearWordsContainer = () => textContainer.innerHTML = ''
```

```css
.word {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #333;
}

.space {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="textContainer"></div>
  <input id="myInput" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I have understood about the limitation of the question. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I really suggest You to try to implement it by Yourself, instead of using some lib. It is not rocket science, You will learn some stuff, and Your page will not have to load additionak kilobytes of external lib ;)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I am looking for some solutions from scratch instead of existing the library.

Comment: If my solution helped You, I would appreciate if You would mark it as a positive answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't give style to text inside an input directly.

I think what you are looking for is an UI element commonly named "tags input" or "chips input" or "pills input"

You might use some javascript or better ("better" being a personal appreciation, see comments below) a js library to input tags/pills like this one

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ (see title Categorizing tags, which uses different colors for each tag)

You can google for others using those names I gave you.

Comment: Thanks for informing about this library and the terms like `tags input`. Thanks a lot

Comment: I disagree with the part "or better a js library" ;)
This stuff is not really complicated, so theres really no need to make Your webpage fat and slow by injecting external libs.

Comment: @grzesiekgs I understand concerns about performance, but I lean more towards using libs. I don't like to reinvent the wheel. I like to solve performance problems when they arise and not doing premature optimization http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/53702 but that's just me. I respect your point and edited answer accordingly.

Comment: @jperelli To be honest, both You and me, are partially right. You are right because - premature optimization is the root of all evil. 
But You are also missing the point of it. It is mostly related to optimization of code, because we should write code for humans not for machines. Libs vs vanilla is not a problem here. Sure frameworks and libs are great and we can't live without them (including myself), but cmon, You really need  jQuery and additional plugin to write such a little feature? It is definitely NOT premature optimization when You cut out off Your bundle over 150 kB of scripts...

Comment: You are right, jQuery is too much for this, the point of my answer was to give the common names so OP could search, the lib I posted was just an example that might help him, and to let him see what was I referring as the UI element

Comment: @jperelli yeah man, I've just pointed out that saying "or better a js library" is not exactly true ;)